# Get docker release version - string required for installation

Tags: list, docker, installation, release

Where we can find docker release string which is required if you want to specify version during the installation? Is there a list ... or maybe a patern which can use to construct this one?

I was not able to find this kind of info within documentation - nor on the web.

For example:

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce
```

is going to install latest version of the docker-ce (at the moment of writing this it is 17.12). Having in mind that this version have few issues i want to avoid, i need to downgrade (read install) specific version.

We can do that with:

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce=<VERSION_STRING>
```

where you can specify version string. Unfortunatelly, there is no any kind of info (at least i was not able to find), which lists specific version strings (release strings) which you can use.

For example, you can find the list of releases [here](https://docs.docker.com/release-notes/docker-ce/). But if we check releases (versions) there and if we try to use them, it will not result with installation, instead it will throw an error.

Example:

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce=17.09.0
```

is going to result with error message: "E: Version '17.09.0' for 'docker-ce' was not found".

Where we can find list of releases (strings) which can use for the installation? Or is there any kind of patern which we can use to construct these (like version~ce-0~system eg. 17.12.0~ce-0~debian) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in [INSTALL DOCKER CE](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-docker-ce-1), you can install a specific version using:

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce=<VERSION>
```

You can check the list of available versions via:

```
apt-cache madison docker-ce
```

The second column of the output specifies the version that you can substitute in the `apt-get install` command.

Comment: what do you do if the madison part doesn't show an output? I have this problem, docker-ce cant be found in apt-cache even though i've added and refreshed the repo, installed docker multiple times on many systems... but this time it doesnt work

Comment: @Oliver i did not notice this kind of behavior before. Are you checking on specific OS? Having in mind that these versions are universal, maybe you can check this list somewhere else, and then just reuse it on the os where you want to install things (if i understood your question properly)?

Comment: @cool i've got to add that this is happening when you use a 32 bit OS instead of 64 bit!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `apt-cache madison docker-ce` command.
The version string is in the second column.

Source: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-docker-ce-1